# Printing path route between two nodes

Tags: java, path, binary-tree

I have the following tree structure:

[image]

Implemented in java like:

```
public class myprogram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Node Boss= new Node(0, "Boss");
        Node Manager1= new Node(1, "Manager1");
        Node Manager2= new Node(1, "Manager2");
        Node AssistantManager = new Node(2,"AssistantManager");
        Node Employee3 = new Node(3,"Employee3");
        Node Employee4 = new Node(3,"Employee4");
        Node Employee1 = new Node(6, "Employee1");
        Node Employee2 = new Node(6, "Employee2");

        Boss.left = Manager1;
        Boss.right = Manager2;

        Manager1.left = AssistantManager;
        Manager1.right = null;

        AssistantManager.left = Employee1;
        AssistantManager.right = Employee2;


        Manager2.left = Employee3;
        Manager2.right = Employee4;
    }

    static class Node
    {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int value;
        String name;
        public Node(int value, String name)
        {
           this.value = value;
           this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

My Goal here is to create a method which finds the path between two nodes in this tree structure. So for example the input might be:

```
String path = findPath(Boss,"AssistantManager",  "Manager2");
System.out.println(path);
```

Given this the 'findPath' method should return 'AssistantManager > Manager1 > Boss < Manager2'.

And if the input was 'Employee1, Employee2', it should give:

```
Employee1 > AssistantManager < Employee2
```

I have been trying to achieve this for a while now so any help on how to code this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to get the path of treeRoot to arg1(AssistantManager) and the path of root to arg2("Manager2")
then find the common ancestor.
e.g. path to assistant manager: Boss - Manager1 - AssisantManager
path to Manager2: Boss - Manager2
so path: AssistantManager - Manager1 - boss - Manager2

and 2nd example
Boss - manager1 - AssistantManager - E1
Boss - manager1 - assistantManager - E2 
= E1 - assistanant manager - e2.

Here is some pseudo code

```
List<String> firstPath = findSinglePath(Node tree, String first) (E1, AssManager, manager1m Boss)
List<String> secondPath = findSinglePath(Node tree, String second) (E2, AssManager, manager1m Boss)
path += "";
for each firstPath
add to path += currentNode + >
if (secondPath contains currentNode) break loop (common ancestor)

for each secondPath
if (firstPath contains currentNode) break loop
else path += < + currentNode
```